# Brain Wave Research PTSD, Depression

Tags: abnormal-psychology, reference-request, clinical-psychology, neuropsychology

Let me preface this with I am a Software Engineer, NOT a neuro-scientist. Please forgive me if my terminology isn't spot on.

I am obsessed with using my skills as a computer scientist to help veterans with PTSD and Depression.

Currently I am attempting to do research on the effects that depression takes on brainwaves. From my, all be it limited, understanding, depression causes a drop in Alpha brainwaves. I want to continue doing research on this topic and nail down as many brainwave signals as possible before I go into the development phase but for the life of me, I have no idea where to begin my research.

What I am looking for is someone to provide me with a resource[s] that will teach me about the effects depression has on brainwaves.

Comment: You should begin by using the available Internet resources on "electroencephalography."  As an aside, Merriam-Webster has a youtube video that expounds upon "electroencephalographically" being the longest word in their dictionary.  You could also begin with articles like this one http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20415629.  EEG is a pretty specialized discipline within neurosciences.  If your goal is to develop a product, you should see if you can find a neuroscientist as a collaborator.

Comment: I'm working on finding a partner right now. I have an EEG device I am planning on using. Thank you very much for the resources and quite possibly the longest word ever.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, +1 :-). An aside: if your product development reaches a phase where you would work with people, there are major ethical considerations to be taken into account, so I second scottb's suggestion for working with a neuroscientist (it's good that you are looking for a partner from the field), and if you would work with people a medical doctor from the related field might be a great contribution to your team as well.

Comment: I was doing some more research on the EEG device I wanted to use [NeuroSky] and I don't think it's sensitive enough for treating depression. It seems in order to properly detect depression you need to probe multiple points on the brain, including the prefrontal cortex. This device doesn't generate data from that area. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: @anongoodnurse a migration would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To be on topic here I advice to remove any reference to self. Further, why the unguided self experimentation? Why don't you seek medical advice and, e.g., start participating in group sessions to help yourself and others in a safe and professional therapeutic environment? We can provide basic scientific background for the sake of science, not for development of psychotherapies and the likes.

Comment: @AliceD the VA provides me therapy which I do take advantage of for PTSD. That said, it doesn't mean I'm not capable of learning about my disorder and contributing to the advancement of treatment. Not many veterans with PTSD have my skill set or the financial and mental capacity to contribute. I have an inside look. I can provide a first hand experience.  I want to help.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the personal references and added some tags. I tried to do so while keeping the intent of the post. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some research which may help is as follows:

Fingelkurts, A. A., Fingelkurts, A. A., Rytsälä, H., Suominen, K., Isometsä, E., & Kähkönen, S. (2007). **[Impaired functional connectivity at EEG alpha and theta frequency bands in major depression](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/hbm.20275)**. *Human brain mapping*, 28(3), 247-261. DOI: [10.1002/hbm.20275](https://doi.org/10.1002/hbm.20275)

Peniston, E. G., & Kulkosky, P. J. (1991). **[Alpha-theta brainwave neurofeedback for Vietnam veterans with combat-related post-traumatic stress disorder](http://charleston.braincoretherapy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/PENISTON-PTSD.pdf)**. *Medical Psychotherapy*, 4(1), 47-60.

Saxby, E., & Peniston, E. G. (1995). **[Alpha‐theta brainwave neurofeedback training: An effective treatment for male and female alcoholics with depressive symptoms](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/1097-4679(199509)51:5%3C685::AID-JCLP2270510514%3E3.0.CO;2-K)**. *Journal of clinical psychology*, 51(5), 685-693.
DOI: [10.1002/1097-4679(199509)51:5%3C685::AID-JCLP2270510514%3E3.0.CO;2-K](https://doi.org/10.1002/1097-4679(199509)51:5%3C685::AID-JCLP2270510514%3E3.0.CO;2-K)